# ansible group vars vs extra vars with parameterized include tasks

Tags: ansible

I'm seeing a value defined in my `group_vars/all` where I expect to see the overridden value from my `-e @local-vars.yml` file. In normal cases, the `-e` wins as per the documentation, but in this more complex case of using parameterized includes, it seems the `-e` value is not involved at the right time.

**playbooks/wtf-vars.yml**

```
---
- hosts: appservers
  tasks:
    - name: WTF is up with this var
      debug: msg={{var1}}
    - include: "{{playbook_dir}}/tasks/wtf-vars-included.yml var1inner={{var1}}"
```

**playbooks/tasks/wtf-vars-included.yml**

```
---
- name: WTF is up with this var included
  debug: msg={{var1inner}}
```

**playbooks/group_vars/all**

```
---
var1: VALUE_FROM_GROUP_VAR_ALL
```

**local-vars.yml**

```
---
var1: VALUE_FROM_DASH_E_FILE
```

Running it with:

`ansible-playbook -i inventory/local-dev.ini -e @local-vars.yml playbooks/wtf-vars.yml` prints this output:

```
PLAY [appservers] *************************************************************

TASK: [WTF is up with this var] ***********************************************
ok: [va] => {
    "msg": "VALUE_FROM_DASH_E_FILE"
}
ok: [vb] => {
    "msg": "VALUE_FROM_DASH_E_FILE"
}

TASK: [WTF is up with this var included] **************************************
ok: [vb] => {
    "msg": "VALUE_FROM_GROUP_VAR_ALL"
}
ok: [va] => {
    "msg": "VALUE_FROM_GROUP_VAR_ALL"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
va                         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
vb                         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

ansible-playbook -i inventory/local-dev.ini -e @local-dev.yml   0.27s user 0.22s system 78% cpu 0.628 total
```

So my question is why doesn't the `-e` value win in both of these cases?

Comment: perhaps this is better suited for ansible's bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, IMHO this is a bug. You should file this as a Github issue with ansible.

Second, I suspect this happens because the include line is parsed earlier, in some buggy waay where the extra vars are not taken into account.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is [ansible/issues/10896](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10896)